# I have a website that has a lot of generated personalized content, how do I work with Akamai?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, web, cdn, akamai

I have a website that has a lot of generated personalized content.  Based on what you do on the site, for instance, if you bought some items in the past, the system won't recommend those items again.   A good thing is that most the web pages have static content (eg. images, header, footer). The problem is that I have many dynamic spots on the page, how can I leverage Akamai to cache as much as possible to reduce server loads?

Comment: Although this may be a fit for another exchange, I wanted to make a comment that CDNs aren't just for caching images, CSS, HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A good first step would be to put Akamai in front of your website and set a default policy of no-store for caching. Then add policies for static object file extensions such as .css, .js, .png, etc.

If you use Akamai DSA service you can accelerate dynamic content and even cache some of it depending.